# In VS Code: [ts] Cannot find module '@src/xxx'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So, I'm using this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "ES6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./lib/",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6"
  },
  "include": [
    "global.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Where you can see the alias `@src` is defined for my code.

`tsc`/`webpack` have no problem building everything but while editing in VS Code, I can't get rid of this error message when I import something as

```
import { xxx } from '@src/xxx';
```

Anyone with the same problem? For me, it's weird to see this because if it's compiling/building properly (from tsc **and** webpack), it means the configuration is correct. So why VS Code is displaying this error msg? It's just annoying but I wanna solve it.

`tsconfig.json` file is also using the standard name (no custom `-p` option for `tsc`) so, VS Code should be able to read it automatically, right? Or any extra configuration is needed for the IDE?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: sadly no. I´m not using aliases now :(

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wonder if they fixed VS Code? I found that I needed to define *.gif in typescript. After that it imported fine for me. with an alias. My other question has my full config and my solution in case it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880363/webpacker-typescript-cant-resolve-rails-asset-pipeline-file

Comment: 4 years and 10 months later, this is still a problem, sigh! Maybe it works in more situations now, but it does not work for my in a trivial (hello world type) example of a monorepo with npm workspaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After long time (I forgot about the question already...) I made it work (don't know if even was possible when the original question was posted).

I'll write here what I did, in case it can help other people :)

Basically, I needed the following:

#### 1. Define paths in `tsconfig.json`

This was in the original question, but including it here too for completion:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@src": ["src"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
    }
}
```

#### 2. Install `tsconfig-paths`

`npm i -D tsconfig-paths`

If you are using **webpack** add `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` too and add the plugin in your `webpack.config.js` like this:

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: 'tsconfig.json' })],
  },
};
```

If you are using **NextJS** the configuration for the plugin goes like this in `next.config.js`:

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.plugins.push(
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: 'tsconfig.json' })
    );

    return config;
  },
};
```

---

I'm not sure if it was just VS Code being improved (therefore my problem was fixed automatically in this one year and a half that passed since I posted the question), but this is what I'm using now and is working fine. Hope it's helpful for others too :)

**Note** (2022/07/31 with TS 4.6.4) - `TsconfigPathsPlugin` is still needed if you try to import non-ts code (i.e. an asset) from TS -by using any other loader-.

Example:

```
import icon from '@assets/icon.svg';
```

I've found that the webpack plugin is still required to achieve that.

Comment: Didn't work in my case, installed the package but when running my nextjs app it says "Cannot find module 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin'".. what did i miss?

Comment: you have to install it as well: npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin

Comment: With Vite, it seems that adding "path" to the root tsconfig.json file did the trick. Meaning no need for step 2 "Install tsconfig.json".

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue. In my case running `Cmd+Shift+P > Typescript: Restart TS Server` did the trick and error message disappeared

Comment: oh I´m sorry, that didn´t fix it... but since I fixed it from last time, let me post what worked for me as an answer :)

Comment: this problem appears when you create new file in a deep nested file structure and use typescript aliase on it. And thanks, not the best solution but it works)

Comment: OMG... I just spent 3 hours on this until you saved me.

Comment: very good!! thank

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays should work out of the box. Just as a side note, make sure the include in your `jsconfig`/`tsconfig` is pointing to correct paths, i.e.

```
// example:
"include": [
  "./**/*.ts",
  "./**/*.tsx"
],
```

Comment: Yeah, things have changed a lot in more than 3 years ;)

Comment: By the way, TsconfigPathsPlugin is still required for imports other than TS. An example could be importing an non TS asset (i.e. an image) from a TS file by using an alias. In that case the webpack plugin is needed ^^

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the typescript version to the node_modules one.
Like so: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1982#issuecomment-1201423277

Answer (score -2):

Just add the below part to your `tsconfig.json` file.

```js
"compilerOptions": {
    ...,
    "baseUrl": ".",
 },
```

***Reason:*** Typescript is not able to identify the `Current_Dir` of your project. So, whenever you try to start with `src`, it cannot understand where `src` is coming from.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything, and it's included in the original question. By the way, there's already an accepted answer, you might want to check on that ;)