# Webpacker/Typescript can't resolve rails asset pipeline file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I'm trying to import a file that is in the rails asset pipeline and for some reason webpack can't find it.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@images/*": ["app/assets/images/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "vendor",
    "public"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Here is my config/webpack/environment.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const customConfig = require('./custom');
const typescript =  require('./loaders/typescript')
const fileLoader = require('./loaders/file');

environment.loaders.append('file', fileLoader)
environment.loaders.append('typescript', typescript)

// Merge custom config
environment.config.merge(customConfig);

module.exports = environment
```

My config/webpack/custom.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app/javascript'),
      '@images': path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'app/assets/images'),
      '@components': '@src/components',
      React: 'react',
      ReactDOM: 'react-dom'
    }
  }
};
```

`import "@images/ajax-circle.gif";` in one of my typsecript files gives error 2307 (can't resolve module) and `webpack-dev-server` is unable to compile  with the following error:

```
ERROR in /Users/brandoncc/dev/my_app/app/javascript/lib/store_management.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/brandoncc/dev/my_app/app/javascript/lib/store_management.ts(1,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module '@images/ajax-circle.gif'.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

It looks like the error comes back to typescript not being able to resolve the file, but I can't figure out why it can't find it.

Comment: The question was why I was getting that error. I already solved it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add a definition for the .gif extension.

Creating `typings.d.ts` with:

```
declare module "*.gif";
```

fixed it.

Comment: fixed the problem for me! But why?

Comment: I haven't used Typescript in a while so I am not 100% sure, but I believe without that declaration, typescript doesn't know to import gif files. I also had to add more modules for other file extensions in that project. I think svg was one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on typescript `paths` feature, you need to use [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) that will resolve the path correctly.
Just add that to your webpack config

```
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ /*configFile: "./path/to/tsconfig.json" */ })]
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response felixmosh. It turns out the path itself wasn't the problem, but rather the extension.. Typescript should give separate errors for the two!